# Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached

Tags: configuration, xdebug

In `app\Mage.ph`p under `dispatchEvent` function i have written `Mage::log($name)` before "return $result" to get events list executed on any action.

In **System > Config** if i save any field value i'm getting

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached.

If i comment or remove `Mage::log($name)` its saving normally.

Could you please help me on why i'm getting this error when i write `Mage::log($name)`

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why logging that variable causes this but the error is due to xdebug, specifically the max_nesting_level being reached. You can probably get rid of the error by increasing this setting to something higher, say 200. http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level

Comment: if i extend it to even 1000 also error repeats. so why logging a variable giving error?

Comment: I remember this being an issue with how xDebug works and in combination to the way some of the internals of Magento are wired you will get this error. I either update the nesting level to 200+ or disable xdebug depending on the severity of the issue.

Comment: The $name variable should only be a string so I can't really see why it would cause an issue. possibly its just being called a lot.

Comment: also are you sure the new config is being loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I just set more for xdebug in php.ini file below:

> xdebug.max_nesting_level=200

It worked !

Here is a more explanation:

> **xdebug.max_nesting_level** 
> Type: integer, Default value: 256
> Controls the protection mechanism for infinite recursion protection. The value >of this setting is the maximum level of nested functions that are allowed >before >the script will be aborted.
>
> Before Xdebug 2.3, the default value was 100.